# How is success probability related to the number of steps of an algorithm?

Tags: probability, problem-solving, computational-complexity

Suppose you have a randomized algorithm whose number of steps is given by $T(n) = 2n^3 + 17$ and whose success probability is 1/2.  Someone presents you with a new algorithm whose number of steps is given by $U(n) = 2n^3 + n + 17$ with a success probability of 3/4.  Which one would you choose?  (Notice these are not complexity classes.  These are the exact number of steps of each algorithm.)

I don't know how to approach this problem.  What is involved here?  I believe something might be missing here.  For example, how many more steps am I willing to invest in order to increase the success probability by 1/100?  I believe something like that might be involved.

You don't have to solve the problem.  I'm more interested in understanding the question.  The concrete case is just to clarify the question and make it clear any of my misunderstandings.

Comment: Some thoughts on how to approach such a problem.  Note that for $n\ge 1$, the number of steps $U(n)$ will always exceed $T(n)$.  So the issue is whether the improved chance of success with the new algorithm (requiring more steps) would "pay off".  In this particular case it is attractive to work with the number of tries that correspond to a "chance of failure" $2^{-k}$.  The second algorithm having chance of failure $2^{-2}$ with a single try, the comparison is easy to work out using an even number of tries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $N_T$ and $N_U$, respectively, be the number of trials for success. $N_T$ and $N_U$ have geometric distributions, so $\mathbb{E}[N_T] = 2$ and $\mathbb{E}[N_U] = \dfrac{4}{3}$. The times to success are then $TN_T$ and $UN_U$. One could then choose the algorithm with the lesser expected time to success, i.e., $2T(n)$ vs $\dfrac{4}{3}U(n)$. Comparing the two one can see that the U-algorithm is always better.

Comment: Why do you say *always* better?  $4/3 U(n)$ seems greater than $2T(n)$ for $n = 1$.

Comment: $\frac{4}{3}U(1) = \frac{80}{3} = 26.67 < 38 = 2T(1)$

Comment: Oh, I see --- you meant $(4/3) U(n)$ not $U(n)$ and similarly for $T(n)$.  Thanks!